# Iterate over multiple lists simultaneously in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have a function that returns an element (elem) that are 3 lists (a,b,c) and I can do the following:

```
for a,b,c in elem:
    do whatever...
```

Is there any way I can do the loop simultaneously with 2 of those elements? kind of something like this:

```
for a,b,c,d,e,f in elem1 and elem2:
    do whatever...
```

Well, assuming elem1 and elem2 have the same size.

Comment: `for a,b,c,d in zip(elem1, elem2)`, for example

Comment: or, `for index in range(len(elem1):` then access `a=elem1[index]`, `b=elem2[index]`, for example

Comment: Thanks, with the combination of both I got what I wanted:

for index1, index2 in zip(elem1,elem2):
    a,b,c=index1
    e,f,g=index2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `zip` function gives you the elements in pairs.

```py
for (a, b, c), (d, e, f) in zip(elem1, elem2):
    do something...
```

You could also do it with indexes

```py
for i in range(len(elem1)):
    (a, b, c), (d, e, f) = elem1[i], elem2[i]
    do something...
```

Answer (score 1):

You may iterate objects elem1 and elem2 together using `zip` function like this:

```
for (a,b,c),(d,e,f) in zip(elem1, elem2):
    do_whatever(a,b,c,d,e,f)
```